# InvalidKeyException in Android app when trying to encrypt with RSA private key

Tags: android, encryption, keystore, android-keystore, key-pair

I'm trying to do encryption/decryption in my Android app with a KeyPair generated within the hardware-backed Keystore. Here's my key generation code:

```
public void createKeys() {
    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar();
    Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar();
    end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator kpGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec spec = null;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(ctx)
                    .setAlias(mAlias)
                    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + mAlias))
                    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1337))
                    .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                    .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                    .build();
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(mAlias,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                    .build();
        }
        kpGenerator.initialize(spec);
        KeyPair kp = kpGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "RSA not supported", e);
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "No such provider: AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "No such provider: AndroidKeyStore");
    }
}
```

Here's me encryption code:

```
public String encrypt(String challenge) {
    try {
        KeyStore mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        mKeyStore.load(null);
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry entry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) mKeyStore.getEntry(mAlias, null);
        Cipher cip = null;
        cip = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cip.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, entry.getPrivateKey());
        byte[] encryptBytes = cip.doFinal(challenge.getBytes());
        String encryptedStr64 = Base64.encodeToString(encryptBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return encryptedStr64;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "No Such Algorithm Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableEntryException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unrecoverable Entry Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "KeyStore Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Invalid Key Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "No Such Padding Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Bad Padding Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Illegal Block Size Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Certificate Exception");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "IO Exception", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Key Generation completes successfully. I also verify that it's hardware-backed using KeyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware(). However, I keep getting an InvalidKeyException on the cip.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, entry.getPrivateKey()) line in encrypt(). The exact exception is

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore operation failed
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption makes only sense if you use a public key. If you "encrypt" with a private key, then you're actually creating a signature. Java/Android has a separate class for that.

Comment: OK, so I tried signing with a private key instead, but I'm still getting Invalid Key Exception: Keystore operation failed. Is there any example code of RSA signing/verification in Android?

Comment: So, did you solve it? You can add your own answer with some code.

Comment: Oh yes, I did. Your answer is correct. I was under the impression that I could encrypt with a private key, because there was an example code in github that did this. Apparently it doesn't work.